# Rails scope searching with wild cards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, sqlite, wildcard

I would like to add the ability to use wildcards to my search.  I'm using rails 3 with SQLite3.  My search is built into the index action of my controller using a scope defined in the model.

```
scope :by_drawing_number, lambda { |drawing_number| where('drawing_number LIKE ?', "#{drawing_number}") unless drawing_number.nil? }
```

I would like to modify this so if the user enters a '?' it is replaced by a '_' for a single character wildcards, and a '*' is replaced by a '%' for multiple character wildcards.

Is there a way to incorporate these substitutions in my scope or will I need to rewrite the scope as a method?  If so, what should the method look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put any logic you want inside a scope. `scope` is basically just syntactic sugar for defining a class method. Something like this ought to work:

```
scope :by_drawing_number, lambda {|drawing_number|
  break if drawing_number.nil?
  match = drawing_number.tr('?*', '_%')
  where('drawing_number LIKE ?', match)
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  The only thing is the ? and the _ should be switched.